# How to insert values into a database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a query. I am unable to insert any values into database. If you can point out whats wrong with the part of code it will be of great help to me. I get proper json output but the values isnt getting inserted into db. Please guide me

Register.php:

```
  $check_partnerEmail = $conn->query("SELECT partnerEmail FROM tbl_partner 
WHERE partnerEmail='$partnerEmail'");
 $partnerEmailCount=$check_partnerEmail->num_rows;

  if ($emailCount==0) {

$newPartner= "INSERT INTO tbl_partner(partnerFirstName, partnerLastName, partnerEmail, partnerPassword, partnerContact, partnerAddress, partnerPracticeArea, partnerExperience, partnerFirmName, partnerBankName, partnerBankRNumber, partnerBankAcNumber, partnerBankAcType, partnerLicenseState, partnerLicenseIdNumber, partnerYearAdmitted) VALUES('$partnerFirstName','$partnerLastName','$partnerEmail','$hashedClientPassword','$partnerContact', '$partnerAddress', '$partnerPracticeArea', '$partnerExperience', '$partnerFirmName', '$partnerBankName', '$partnerBankRNumber', '$partnerBankAcNumber', '$partnerBankAcType', '$partnerLicenseState', '$partnerLicenseIdNumber', '$partnerYearAdmitted' )";

if ($newPartner=== false){
      echo "error!";
    $result = array();
    $result[] = array("status" => "Error");
      }else
    {
     echo "Your have been signed up - please now Log In";
     $result = array();
     $result[] = array("First Name" => $partnerFirstName, "Last Name" => $partnerLastName, "Email" => $partnerEmail, "Password" => $hashedClientPassword, "Contact" => $partnerContact, "Address" => $partnerAddress "Practice Area" => $partnerPracticeArea "Experience" => $partnerExperience "Firm Name" => $partnerFirmName "Bank Name" => $partnerBankName "AC Number" => $partnerBankAcNumber "Routing Number" => $partnerBankRNumber "AC Type" => $partnerBankAcType "State" => $partnerLicenseState "License ID" => $partnerLicenseIdNumber "Year Admitted" => $partnerYearAdmitted "status" => "success");
    } 

}else {

echo "Already Exists";
$result = array();
$result[] = array("status" => "Error");

 }

echo json_encode($result);

}
```

Connection.php

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="Test";

    $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
    if(!$conn)
    {
        die("Error :".mysqli_error($conn));
    }
?>
```

Register.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>  

<h2>Reg User</h2>
<form method="post" action="clientRegister.php">
      <label>
        First Name:<input type="text" name="clientFirstName"><br/>
        Last Name:<input type="text" name="clientLastName"><br/>
        Email:<input type="text" name="clientEmail"><br/>
        Password:<input type="password" name="clientPassword"><br/>
        Confirm Password:<input type="password" name="clientCPassword"><br/>
        Contact:<input type="text" name="clientContact"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit">
      </label>
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [**your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: I don't see executing your `$newPartner` query.

Comment: What goes wrong? Do you get a mysql error? Does one of your error traps echo out?

Comment: @u_mulder typing error

Comment: Do you know what is __executing a query__?

Comment: @NavedShaikh, there shouldn't be any typing errors because you should be copying and pasting your _exact_ code. How else are we supposed to know what errors are relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You have a syntax error on this lin, Use the **,** between each statement

```
 $result[] = array("First Name" => $partnerFirstName, "Last Name" => $partnerLastName, "Email" => $partnerEmail, "Password" => $hashedClientPassword, "Contact" => $partnerContact, "Address" => $partnerAddress "Practice Area" => $partnerPracticeArea "Experience" => $partnerExperience "Firm Name" => $partnerFirmName "Bank Name" => $partnerBankName "AC Number" => $partnerBankAcNumber "Routing Number" => $partnerBankRNumber "AC Type" => $partnerBankAcType "State" => $partnerLicenseState "License ID" => $partnerLicenseIdNumber "Year Admitted" => $partnerYearAdmitted "status" => "success");
```

It is true

```
 $result[] = array("First Name" => $partnerFirstName, "Last Name" => $partnerLastName, "Email" => $partnerEmail, "Password" => $hashedClientPassword, "Contact" => $partnerContact, "Address" => $partnerAddress ,"Practice Area" => $partnerPracticeArea, "Experience" => $partnerExperience ,"Firm Name" => $partnerFirmName, "Bank Name" => $partnerBankName ,"AC Number" => $partnerBankAcNumber, "Routing Number" => $partnerBankRNumber, "AC Type" => $partnerBankAcType, "State" => $partnerLicenseState, "License ID" => $partnerLicenseIdNumber, "Year Admitted" => $partnerYearAdmitted, "status" => "success");
```

2-Also you have a syntax error at last line.remove **}**

3-Include connection database file on register php file for excute query

```
include 'Connection.php';
.
.
.
    $newPartner = "INSERT INTO tbl_partner(partnerFirstName, partnerLastName, partnerEmail, partnerPassword, partnerContact, partnerAddress, partnerPracticeArea, partnerExperience, partnerFirmName, partnerBankName, partnerBankRNumber, partnerBankAcNumber, partnerBankAcType, partnerLicenseState, partnerLicenseIdNumber, partnerYearAdmitted) VALUES('$partnerFirstName','$partnerLastName','$partnerEmail','$hashedClientPassword','$partnerContact', '$partnerAddress', '$partnerPracticeArea', '$partnerExperience', '$partnerFirmName', '$partnerBankName', '$partnerBankRNumber', '$partnerBankAcNumber', '$partnerBankAcType', '$partnerLicenseState', '$partnerLicenseIdNumber', '$partnerYearAdmitted' )";
          if ($conn->query($newPartner) === TRUE) {
              echo "New record created successfully";
          } else {
              echo "Error: " . $newPartner . "<br>" . $conn->error;
          }

.
.
.
```

Answer (score -1):

execute the query $newpartner using $result = con->query($newpartner);